# getCurrentPosition doesn't update the location

Tags: javascript, ios, geolocation, titanium-mobile

I am working on an app which requires user's current position constantly.

I am facing an issue i.e. first time Device get the latitude and longitude of user's current location and cached it I think, and returns me same lat,lng every time. Is there any way to remove cached location from device ? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Some of my code:

```
Titanium.Geolocation.purpose = "Recieve User Location";
Ti.Geolocation.accuracy = Ti.Geolocation.ACCURACY_BEST;
Ti.Geolocation.distanceFilter = 5;
Ti.Geolocation.activityType = Ti.Geolocation.ACTIVITYTYPE_FITNESS;

Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e)
{
    if (!e.success || e.error)
    {
        alert('error ' + JSON.stringify(e.error));
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        var longitudeFore;
        var latitudeFore;

        longitudeFore = e.coords.longitude;
        latitudeFore = e.coords.latitude; 

        latitudeFore = parseFloat(latitudeFore);
        longitudeFore = parseFloat(longitudeFore);

        latitudeFore = latitudeFore.toFixed(6);
        longitudeFore = longitudeFore.toFixed(6);

        alert(latitudeFore + '\n' + longitudeFore);
    }
});
```

Please can someone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have distance filter applied, you will never receive the current location unless it exceeds the filtered distance from the cashed location. One way to get current location all the time is to remove this distance filter, or stop location services and start them again which I think will give you the last known location.